# Inequalities of expressions completely symmetric in their variables

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

We often encounter inequalities of symmetric expressions, i.e. the expression doesn't change if the variables in it are interchanged, with the prior knowledge of a certain relation between those variables. In all such cases that I have encountered thus far, we can find the extremum of the expression by letting the variables equal. Here are a few examples:

$(1)$ Given $a + b + c = 3$ ($a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$), the extremum of $ab + bc + ca$ is achieved when $a = b= c$. Hence the extremum is $3$, which is expected.

$(2)$ In a triangle $ABC$, the extremum of $\cos A + \cos B + \cos C$ is achieved when $A = B = C$. With the knowledge that $A + B + C = \pi$, the extremum is $\frac32$, which is, again, expected.

$(3)$ Similar to the previous one, in a triangle $ABC$, the extremum of $\sin \frac{A}2\sin\frac{B}2\sin\frac{C}2$ is achieved when $A = B = C = \frac{π}{3}$. The extremum is $\frac{1}{8}$. Expected, once again.

What I have noticed is this technique doesn't work when expressions remain invariant under a cyclic shift of the variables. So, with the groundwork laid, here are my questions. If this technique **IS** valid, then

$1.$ **How can one go about proving that the technique works?**

$2.$ **How do I know if the extremum is a maximum or a minimum. Moreover, are these local extrema or global extrema?**

$3.$ **Does this technique have an "official" name?**

If the technique is **NOT** valid, please provide explanations and counterexamples.

**EDIT:** The values encountered as extrema above were expected since we have proofs for the individual inequalities. So please don't provide proofs for them, as answers. Instead, what I am specifically looking for is a general proof that expressions completely symmetric in their variables indeed achieve their extrema when the variables equal each other.

Answer (score 1):

For example.

1. $\max(xy+xz+yz)=3$ not because it happens for $x=y=z=1$.

$\max(xy+xz+yz)=3$ because $xy+xz+yz\leq\frac{1}{3}(x+y+z)^2\Leftrightarrow$
$(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2\geq0$ with equality for $x=y=z$.

The extremum indeed achieved when $x=y=z=1$, but without proof like my it's nothing!

2. $\max(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=\frac{3}{2}$ not because it happens for $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=60^{\circ}$.

$\max(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=\frac{3}{2}$ because 
$$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma\leq\frac{3}{2}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow1-2\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}+2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\leq\frac{3}{2}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow4\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}-4\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}+1\geq0,$$
which is obvious.
The extremum indeed occurs for $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$, but without proof it's nothing!

The following inequality is symmetric, but the equality does not occur for equality case of variables.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $a+b+c=3$. Prove that:
$$(a^2-ab+b^2)(a^2-ac+c^2)(b^2-bc+c^2)\leq12$$ 
The maximum value is $12$, but for $a=b=c=1$ we get $3$.

Comment: That's right. But then the extremum is indeed achieved when $x=y=z$, isn't it?

Comment: Plus, I didn't mean $\max(xy+yz+zx) = 3$ "because" it happens for $x = y = z = 1$. I mean, $\max(xy+yz+zx) = 3$ "when" $x=y=z=1$.

Comment: Again, for the others, I didn't mean "because", but "when".

Comment: I know. But my question didn't want proofs of the individual inequalities cited as examples. It demanded a general proof that expressions completely symmetric in their variables indeed achieve their extremum when the variables equal each other.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to downvote the answer, because it didn't cater to my question well.

Comment: Can you explain to me why $xyz + xzy + yzx + yxz + zxy + zyx$ should have an extremum value of $\frac{250}{9}$ when $x+y+z = 5$?

Comment: How do you prove that the maximum value is 12?

Comment: @Nilabro Saha I am ready, but you don't want proofs. The equality occurs for $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0)$.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. If you're providing a counterexample, I definitely need a proof. :-)

Comment: @Nilabro Saha No problems! Open new topic with this problem and I'll prove it.

Comment: Just add it to your answer, maybe?

Comment: @Nilabro Saha I can not! It's another problem.

Comment: Done. Please check