# Proving the inequality $(a^2-ab+b^2)(c^2-ac+a^2)(b^2-bc+c^2) \le 12$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

This is a follow up question to my previous post ["Inequalities of expressions completely symmetric in their variables"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132200/inequalities-of-expressions-completely-symmetric-in-their-variables). An answer provided a counterexample to me reasoning: under the constraints $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}^+$ and $a+b+c=3$,

$$
(a^2-ab+b^2)(c^2-ac+a^2)(b^2-bc+c^2) \le 12.
$$

I demanded a proof for this inequality, however since it was an entirely different question, I felt the need for a new post.

Comment: This is not symmetric. Is the second factor supposed to be $c^2-bc+b^2$?

Comment: Corrected it. It should be fine now.

Comment: @Nilabro Saha The variables should be non-negatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a\geq b\geq c\geq0$.
Hence,
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2)\leq(a^2-ab+b^2)a^2b^2=((a+b)^2-3ab)a^2b^2\leq(9-3ab)a^2b^2=$$
$$=12(3-ab)\cdot\frac{ab}{2}\cdot\frac{ab}{2}\leq12\left(\frac{3-ab+\frac{ab}{2}+\frac{ab}{2}}{3}\right)^3=12$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand how you asserted that $\prod_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2) \le (a^2-ab+b^2)a^2b^2$. Mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: @Nilabro Saha Because $a^2-ac+c^2\leq a^2$ and $b^2-bc+c^2\leq b^2$.

Comment: Also, why should $(9-3ab)a^2b^2\le 12$?

Comment: @Nilabro Saha It's Just AM-GM. See my fixing.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg For this to be complete, you should also note that the maximum $12$ is in fact attained. Nice example, btw.

Comment: Now I see it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity.. Does this expression have a minimum value?

Comment: @NilabroSaha $a=b=0\,$.

Comment: Oh! Yea, my bad.

Comment: If $a=2$, $b=1$, $c=0$, then then the maximum of 12 is attained. From the answer it follows that there is no other way to get the maximum with $a\ge b\ge c\ge 0$. That's because to get $=$ instead of $\le$ everywhere in the answer, we need $c=0$, $a+b=3$, $3-ab=ab/2$.